# Is there a way to hide the current directory while typing commands in Cygwin

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin

It is kinda annoying to have the path show each time i write a command. Is there a way to make it so that only the $ sign shows when i execute a command by pressing enter?

[image]

Comment: What is shown here, is the command prompt, and **you** are the one who defines this prompt (typically in your ~/.zshrc). If you don't like your prompt, just redefine it in the way you want for instance  `PS1='$'` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, set your PS1 environment variable. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

To set this as default in cygwin:

1. open `bash.bashrc`, for me that was in `C:\tools\cygwin\etc\bash.bashrc`
2. Find the variable `PS1` and change the lower case `w` to an upper case

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\W\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
                                               ^ this one
```

3. Restart your terminal

If you already have a high degree of context, for instance when working in vs code, you *could* change the entire variable to something very minimalist:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\[\e[32m\]\[\e[33m\]\W\[\e[0m\] $ '
```

Which will produce something like this:

[image]

Comment: Just one other question. Can i also hide error messages?

Comment: Sorry I don't know that one off the top of my head. You'll want to look into redirecting stderr.

Comment: Thank you i will. Just to be clear i'm talking about the error messages you get when you for example type an invalid command.